# Is it possible to use jQuery on an element that is in an included HTML file?

Tags: jquery, html, include

As title sais, is it possible to use jQuery on an element that is in an included HTML file? either with HTML or jQuery include.

Extra info:

Example:
I have A.html and B.html which both includes 1.html

There is an element in 1.html which I dont want to show in A.html but I do want it to show in B.html.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "included HTML file"?

Comment: Something like

<!-- include dashboard -->
            <div src=" '/HTMLCommon/includes/dashboard.html' "></div>

Comment: And how do you include this file? Because if you include it (as i understand it), then it is part of DOM so? And your posted code doesn't make sense, so?!

Comment: I tried with HTML <!-- include dashboard -->
            <div src=" '/HTMLCommon/includes/dashboard.html' "></div> and with jQuery:
<div id="include"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#include').load('/HTMLCommon/includes/dashboard.html');
           
            });

Comment: So use `load()` complete callback or for handling events, delegate them. Your question is too vague and doesn't really make sense so you'd have better to post a concrete sample of what you are looking for

Comment: I am pretty sure by checking the jQuery documentation that the first " / " is not needed... From jQuery's docs : `$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );` , so have you tried `$('#include').load('HTMLCommon/includes/dashboard.html');` ?

Comment: @anima_incognita the include is working fine. its just that I cant show or hide elements which are in the included html file

Comment: @job `load()` is async, so again, USE relevant complete callback, check the DOC

Comment: @A.Wolff Im sorry, im trying to understand what you are saying, im fairly new to this. So do you mean that I should use this?

$('#include').load('/HTMLCommon/includes/dashboard.html');

Because this has the load() in it?

Comment: I mean use: `$('#include').load('/HTMLCommon/includes/dashboard.html', function(){/* now content is loaded and you can use any jq method on this content*/});`

Comment: @A.Wolff Oke, cool. Im going to try that tommorow :)

Comment: @A.Wolff Aight. that did the trick. thanks for the answer and more important the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If you load some additional DOMs from external resources, make sure you initiate function after all DOMs loaded, or use global selectors.

Let's suppose you have `<div class="foo"></div>` loaded after main document finished, to set `onclick` listener of that element from main document use:

`$(document).on('click', '.foo', function() { ... });`